# Can't cd Within Init.d Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unicorn

I'm at an impasse and need help.
Implementing a Unicorn init script that throws an error when it tries to change working directory to my application path (in order to execute 'bundle exec unicorn').

Capistrano output is as follows.

```
DEBUG [50572a40]  Starting Unicorn Daemon for accreu 
DEBUG [50572a40]  Starting Unicorn Daemon for accreu 
DEBUG [50572a40]  /etc/init.d/unicorn_accreu: 44: cd: 
DEBUG [50572a40]  Starting Unicorn Daemon for accreu 
DEBUG [50572a40]  can't cd to /home/ubuntu/apps/accreu;
DEBUG [50572a40]  Starting Unicorn Daemon for accreu 
DEBUG [50572a40]  
DEBUG [50572a40]  cd /home/ubuntu/apps/accreu; bundle exec unicorn -D -c config/unicorn.rb -E production
DEBUG [50572a40]  
DEBUG [50572a40]  /home/ubuntu
```

The relevant init lines are:

```
UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c <%= fetch(:unicorn_config) %> -E production"
CMD="cd <%= fetch(:prime_path) %>; bundle exec unicorn $UNICORN_OPTS"
```

Comment: Are you starting it before some required filesystem is mounted?

Comment: No actively. This is an AMI, so let me check its' partitions.

Comment: So far I have gotten it to change directories by removing the semicolon ';' from the end.

Comment: It does not place the 'bundle exec unicorn' in the correct dir.

Comment: unicorn daemon starts, but since its' not within the application directory none of the app is loaded. Confirmed by visiting server address.

Comment: totally baffling. It works if I ssh in, cd to appdir, and exec command. Everything is the same except perhaps what user role the init script is running as..

Comment: New developments. Sourced the error from logs as 'Exception PG::ConnectionBad'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add 'host: localhost' within my production database.yml file.